# Connection error to database in cloud

Tags: mysql, jdbc, cloud

I have problem context xml file.

I have wrote below mentioned code but, i couldn't connect to database:

```
Resource name = "jdbc/Examsite" auth="Container" 
                type="javax.sql.DataSource"  maxActive="20" maxIdle="30"  
                maxWait="10000" driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" 
                url=" jdbc:mysql://http://34.209.206.56:3306/oracle_exam_last " 
                username="****" password="****" />
```

Comment: in MySQL work branch  i have checked it work.  but in jdbc it is not work

Comment: and your error is?

Comment: error : org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create JDBC driver of class 'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver' for connect URL ' jdbc:mysql://34.209.206.56:3306/oracle_exam_last'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a problem in your URL :

```
url=" jdbc:mysql://http://34.209.206.56:3306/oracle_exam_last " 
//------------------^^^--------------------------------------^
```

You should not specify the protocole `http` just the ip and the port number and the database name, also don't make a space in your url :

```
url=" jdbc:mysql://34.209.206.56:3306/oracle_exam_last"
```

Comment: org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create JDBC driver of class 'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver' for connect URL ' jdbc:mysql://34.209.206.56:3306/oracle_exam_last'      -   no result  :-(

Comment: YCF_L it worked at last. you were right, there was space., i have reduce space.